# jquery xml load & parse

Tags: xml, google-chrome, jquery, xml-parsing, get

Chrome an IE do not load or parse my xml. I test it on the Server not local. Chrome jumps in Error Function. On FF it is all ok.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        aSync: false,
        success: function onXMLloaded(xml) 
        {       
            console.log('Success');
            // loop for each item
            $(xml).find('item').each(function loopingItems(value){  
                // create an object
                var obj={urls:$(this).find("urls").text()};
                // push in object
                videos_array.push(obj);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error');
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Complete');
                    }
```

Have anyone an idea? Thanks so much!

Comment: I've never seen something like `success: function onXMLloaded(xml) ` -- try replacing it with `success: function(xml) `

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but no effect. I see the xml in my console but it jumps into error and complete.

Comment: Any JavaScript errors?

Comment: no errors or something else in the console.

Comment: OK. Here is how ist works:

console.log('Beginne XML zu laden');
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "text",
        aSync: false,
        success: function (text) 
        {       
            console.log('Success');
            // loop for each item
            $(text).find('item').each(function loopingItems(value){    
                // create an object
                var obj={urls:$(this).find("urls").text()};
                // push in object
                videos_array.push(obj);
            });
        },

Thanks all!

Comment: If you found a working answer, please submit your own answer to your question and accept it for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is how ist works:

> `console.log('Beginne XML zu laden');  $.ajax({     type: 'GET',
>   url: XML_PATH,     dataType: "text",     aSync: false,     success:
>   function (text) { 
>         console.log('Success'); 
>         // loop for each item 
>         $(text).find('item').each(function loopingItems(value){
>            // create an object var 
>            obj={urls:$(this).find("urls").text()};
>           // push in object 
>           videos_array.push(obj);
>          }); 
>       },

`

The DataType was the problem. Now works fine :-) Thanks all!